# Identify duplicated values in the same columns across undefined sheets using Apps Script

Tags: javascript, function, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have a spreadsheet that is growing **undefined** in number of sheets.
I want to **highlight duplicated** values in the same columns **across all undefined sheets**.
I can do it with conditional formating, but as the number of sheets will grow a lot, **this approach isn't valid**.

I tried something like:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();

function readSheetData() {
  var rowRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, lastRow, lastColumn);
  var rangeArray = rowRange.getValues();
  // Convert to a one dimensional array
  rangeArray = [].concat.apply([], rangeArray);
  return rangeArray;
}

// Creates an array with data from a chosen column
function readColumnData(column) {
  var columnRange = sheet.getRange(1, column, lastRow);
  var rangeArray = columnRange.getValues();
  // Convert to one dimensional array
  rangeArray = [].concat.apply([], rangeArray);
  return rangeArray;
}

// Creates an array with data from a chosen row
function readRowData(row) {
  var rowRange = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, lastColumn);
  var rangeArray = rowRange.getValues();
  // Convert to one dimensional array
  rangeArray = [].concat.apply([], rangeArray);
  Logger.log(rangeArray);
  return rangeArray;
}

// Sort data and find duplicates
function findDuplicates(data) {
  var sortedData = data.slice().sort();
  var duplicates = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < sortedData.length - 1; i++) {
    if (sortedData[i + 1] == sortedData[i] && sortedData[i] != "") {
      duplicates.push(sortedData[i]);
    }
  }
  return duplicates;
}

// Find locations of all duplicates
function getIndexes(data, duplicates) {
  var column = 2;
  var indexes = [];
  i = -1;
  // Loop through duplicates to find their indexes
  for (var n = 0; n < duplicates.length; n++) {
    while ((i = data.indexOf(duplicates[n], i + 1)) != -1) {
      indexes.push(i);
    }
  }
  return indexes;
}

// Highlight all instances of duplicate values in a sheet
function highlightSheetDuplicates(indexes) {
  var row;
  for (n = 0; n < indexes.length; n++) {
    row = 1;
    if (indexes[n] > lastColumn) {
      row = Math.floor(indexes[n] / lastColumn);
      indexes[n] = indexes[n] - lastColumn * row;
      row++;
    }
    sheet.getRange(row, indexes[n] + 1).setBackground("red");
  }
}


// Highlight all instances of duplicate values in a column
function highlightColumnDuplicates(column, indexes) {
  for (n = 0; n < indexes.length; n++) {
    sheet.getRange(indexes[n] + 1, column).setBackground("red");
  }
}

// Highlight all instances of duplicate values in a row
function highlightRowDuplicates(row, indexes) {
  for (n = 0; n < indexes.length; n++) {
    sheet.getRange(row, indexes[n] + 1).setBackground("red");
  }
}

//----------- Main -------------

function sheetMain() {
  var data = readSheetData();
  var duplicates = findDuplicates(data);
  var indexes = getIndexes(data, duplicates);
  highlightSheetDuplicates(indexes);
}

function columnMain(column) {
  var data = readColumnData(column);
  var duplicates = findDuplicates(data);
  var indexes = getIndexes(data, duplicates);
  highlightColumnDuplicates(column, indexes);
}

function rowMain(row) {
  var data = readRowData(row);
  var duplicates = findDuplicates(data);
  var indexes = getIndexes(data, duplicates);
  highlightRowDuplicates(row, indexes);
}

// ---------- Menu ----------
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('DUPLICATED')
    .addItem('Sheet', 'sheetMain')
    .addItem('Row', 'showRowPrompt')
    .addItem('Column', 'showColumnPrompt')
    .addToUi();
}

// ---------- Prompt ----------
function showColumnPrompt() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response = ui.prompt(
    'Find Duplicates',
    'Enter letter of column to search:',
    ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  // Get user response, run main
  var button = response.getSelectedButton();
  var text = response.getResponseText();
  if (button == ui.Button.OK) {
    text = sheet.getRange(text + "1");
    text = text.getColumn();
    columnMain(text);
  }
}

function showRowPrompt() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response = ui.prompt(
    'Find Duplicates',
    'Enter number of row to search:',
    ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  // Get user response, run main
  var button = response.getSelectedButton();
  var text = response.getResponseText();
  if (button == ui.Button.OK) {
    rowMain(text);
  }
}
```

But it only works in columns/rows of the **active sheet**.
It also enables a trigger menu that is quite usefull.

**The expected result:**

1. Run script from the menu
2. Highlight with red background cells in Sheet_1 A:A, Sheet_2 A:A, Sheet_3 A:A... that have the same values.
3. Do the same with values in Sheet_1 D:D, Sheet_2 D:D, Sheet_3 D:D
4. Do the same with values in Sheet_1 J:J, Sheet_2 J:J, Sheet_3 J:J
5. Delete manually some highlighted rows
6. Run script again
7. Breath deep and drink some tea

P.S. I don't want to look for duplicates in the first row (fixed header)

I will be **super grateful** if someone can help me with this problem that I've been working for three days without finding the right solution, I have tried different ways but I cannot find the ideal solution.

**Thanks!** ‍

Comment: What have you done to debug it?

Comment: Is a duplicate a row that is identical on every column of every sheet?

Comment: I've tried the Apps Script debugger and the code is working fine. But I don't get the result I'm look for: **search for duplicates across all sheets**

Comment: If you don't get the result your looking for then everything is not fine.

Comment: Yes, every sheet have the same column structure. The first row of all of them is header, where actually I don't want to find for duplicates.

Comment: Are you looking for duplicates across all three sheets or just one at a time?

Comment: All three sheets. I want to highlight the duplicated values on all sheets at once.

Comment: How large are the sheets?

Comment: You say `delete some rows`. How do you determine which rows to delete?

Comment: In the global variables you have:  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

Anywhere you reference "sheet" it will call up the active sheet.  It seems like you want to loop through all sheets, or at least a set of sheets.  If that is the case, you don't want to set sheet as a global variable.

Comment: Sheets can be at most 3000 rows. I want to delete some of this rows manually after highlighted, so it doesn't really affect the script. Yes, but getActiveSheet() gets just the sheet you have open. I want to get all sheets in spreadsheet.

Comment: and what constitutes a duplicate and how do you determine which rows to delete

Comment: a duplicated cell must be a cell that contains exactly the same string as in other cell... is something like conditional formating: =countif($A$2:$A$3000,A2)>1 but in a script that runs in all sheets at the same time

Comment: okay then how to determine what rows get deleted

Comment: Please provide a table of representative data that does not contain private information

Comment: I want to detele it manually. Dont worry about deletion. We can forget this point.

Comment: This is an example of the expected result: [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T3FKwjwN26pdjotSgOqdmUywvO4quyuhsESPJd-siQM/edit?usp=sharing) in red the cells containing a string repeated in other cells across the spreadsheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumption:
Original values come from earliest sheets so most copies are found in later sheets or at least last rows in first sheet.

```
function findDuplicateInMultipleColumnsAndMultipleSheets() {
  const names = ['Sheet1', 'Sheet2', 'Sheet3'];//sheet names included
  const colors= ['#ff0000','#ffff00','#00ffff'];//added different colors for each column
  const cols = [1, 4, 10];//columns
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const shts = ss.getSheets().filter(s => { return ~names.indexOf(s.getName()) });//only gets the sheets with names in the names array
  let uA = new Array(cols.length);//create unique array for all three cols
  cols.forEach((c, i) => {
    uA[i]= new Array(1);
    shts.forEach((sh, j) => {
      let vs = sh.getRange(2, c, sh.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getValues().flat();
      vs.forEach((v, k) => {
        if (!~uA[i].indexOf(v)) {
          uA[i].push(v);//unique array for each column for all three sheets
        }
      });
    })
    let obj={};//used to record first matches which are assumed to be originals
    shts.forEach((sh,j)=>{
       let vs = sh.getRange(2, c, sh.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getValues().flat();
      vs.forEach((e, k) => {
        if (~uA[i].indexOf(e)) {
          if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(e)) {
            obj[e]=1;//first one gets recorded
          } else {
            if(e) {
              sh.getRange(k+2,c).setBackground(colors[i]);//copies get background changed if they're not blank
            }
          }
        }
      });
    })
  });
}
```

My Data:
Sheet1:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 | COL9 | COL10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| string1 | 25 | 25 | string1 | 3 | 2 | 24 | 0 | 1 | string1 |
| string2 | 9 | 22 | string2 | 23 | 3 | 11 | 20 | 4 | string2 |
| string3 | 7 | 28 | string3 | 19 | 19 | 22 | 7 | 3 | string3 |
| string4 | 10 | 21 | string4 | 25 | 12 | 11 | 0 | 0 | string4 |
| string5 | 2 | 9 | string5 | 7 | 6 | 29 | 15 | 4 | string5 |
| string6 | 21 | 26 | string6 | 21 | 18 | 20 | 1 | 6 | string6 |
| string7 | 7 | 25 | string7 | 3 | 21 | 5 | 28 | 29 | string7 |
| string8 | 17 | 2 | string8 | 6 | 19 | 20 | 26 | 2 | string8 |
| string9 | 9 | 26 | string9 | 12 | 21 | 20 | 19 | 18 | string9 |
| string4 | 9 | 26 | string4 | 12 | 21 | 20 | 19 | 18 | string4 |
|  | 9 | 26 |  | 12 | 21 | 20 | 19 | 18 |  |

[image]

Sheet2:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 | COL9 | COL10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| string8 | 28 | 6 | string8 | 14 | 28 | 0 | 9 | 29 | string8 |
| string9 | 13 | 24 | string9 | 27 | 1 | 26 | 22 | 21 | string9 |
| string10 | 20 | 17 | string10 | 9 | 26 | 10 | 24 | 16 | string10 |
| string11 | 12 | 24 | string11 | 17 | 28 | 17 | 29 | 24 | string11 |
| string12 | 18 | 27 | string12 | 4 | 23 | 6 | 12 | 11 | string12 |
| string13 | 8 | 29 | string13 | 21 | 18 | 1 | 24 | 7 | string13 |
| string14 | 8 | 21 | string14 | 14 | 29 | 2 | 7 | 19 | string14 |
| string15 | 23 | 5 | string15 | 2 | 20 | 8 | 8 | 9 | string15 |
| string16 | 1 | 12 | string16 | 22 | 23 | 19 | 5 | 27 | string16 |
|  | 1 | 12 |  | 22 | 23 | 19 | 5 | 27 |  |

[image]

Sheet3:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 | COL9 | COL10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| string15 | 21 | 14 | string15 | 27 | 26 | 3 | 23 | 24 | string15 |
| string16 | 10 | 25 | string16 | 22 | 6 | 20 | 25 | 21 | string16 |
| string17 | 3 | 10 | string17 | 6 | 18 | 28 | 3 | 10 | string17 |
| string18 | 19 | 20 | string18 | 6 | 25 | 1 | 11 | 16 | string18 |
| string19 | 5 | 0 | string19 | 14 | 29 | 27 | 2 | 21 | string19 |
| string20 | 8 | 8 | string20 | 13 | 9 | 27 | 13 | 5 | string20 |
| string21 | 18 | 6 | string21 | 1 | 24 | 22 | 3 | 7 | string21 |
| string22 | 6 | 4 | string22 | 26 | 5 | 25 | 5 | 4 | string22 |
| string23 | 5 | 28 | string23 | 6 | 7 | 17 | 19 | 25 | string23 |
|  | 5 | 28 |  | 6 | 7 | 17 | 19 | 25 |  |

[image]

I was working on something else and I used this problem as an example and this way works pretty well and you can change the sheets that it works on and the columns that you want to include just by adding them to the appropriate array.  I

```
function getCopyData() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const names = ['Sheet1', 'Sheet2', 'Sheet3'];//sheetames to include
  const colors = ['#ffff00', '#ff00ff', '#00ffff'];//colors to use
  const cols = [1, 4, 10];columns to check you can add more
  const shts = ss.getSheets().filter(s => names.includes(s.getName()));
  const vals = shts.map(s => s.getRange(2, 1, s.getLastRow() - 1, s.getLastColumn()).getValues()).map(a => { return a.map(r => { let row = []; cols.forEach((c, i) => { row.push(r[c - 1]) }); return row; }) });//only gets values for columns that you want
  let uA = Array.from(cols, u => ({}));//create an array of independent objects
  vals.forEach((a, i) => {
    a.forEach((r, j) => {
      cols.forEach((c, k) => {
        if (r[k]) {//doesn't do anything if value is empty
          if (!uA[k].hasOwnProperty(r[k])) {//checks to see if this value has already been found
            uA[k][r[k]] = 0;//if it  hasn't been found then it's the original
          } else {
            uA[k][r[k]] += 1;//if it has then it's a copy
            shts[i].getRange(j + 2, c).setBackground(colors[k%colors.length]);//sets the background color for copies
          }
        }
      });
    })
  });
}
```

Comment: Many thanks @Cooper it works! also the comments in code are so helpful. Is there any way to avoid blank cell nackground coloring?

Comment: Probably. I didn’t have a blank cells my data. I’ll take a look at it

Comment: That seems to handle the blank situation

Comment: Many thanks @Cooper you solved my problem! :)